# Ruby transpose table, array to string, regex

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, transpose

In Ruby I would have this array of arrays:

```
[[1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1]]
```

which translates into this matrix or table (no headers):

```
11100
11100
00011
```

What I want to do is to take every element of each array in the array to transpose the array, for instance, in the above table/array I would have this output as an array of arrays:

```
[[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
```

or this table

```
110
110
110
001
001
```

Finally, once the above is accomplished, I would like to convert every array in the array to a string which would exclude any values that are not consecutive 1s, for instance, if I convert the array [1,0,1,1,1,0,1] to a string where the non consecutive 1s are excluded I should get something like this: 111. Note that the first, second, sixth and seventh element are excluded because they are not consecutive 1s.

Comment: \n means nothing, a typo.

Comment: If 7th element is excluded then why third element is not excluded its preceded by `0`?

Comment: What do you want as output when there are no consecutive ones? When there are multiple sets of consecutive ones? (e.g. [1,1,0,1,1])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, all you need is `Array#transpose`.

```
array.transpose
#=>  [[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
```

then you can do the following

```
.map {|arr| arr.join.scan(/11+/)}
```

to count the consecutive ones. The `join` converts each subarray to a string, then `scan` checks for two or more consecutive `1`s.

Altogether:

```
array.transpose.map {|arr| arr.join.scan(/11+/)}
#=> [["11"], ["11"], ["11"], [], []]
```

If you want to remove the empty arrays, @Doorknob notes that you can append a `reject`:

```
array.transpose.map {|arr| arr.join.scan(/11+/)}.reject(&:empty?)
#=> [["11"], ["11"], ["11"]]
```

Comment: `flatten` gets rid of empty arrays (where there are no consecutive ones), perhaps unnecessary.

Comment: And what if there is `[1,1,0,1,1]`? Then there will be two seperate strings. You probably want `.transpose.map {|arr| arr.join.scan(/11+/).join}.reject(&:empty?)`.

Comment: @Doorknob good point. I didn't consider that scenario. I've updated my answer and asked the OP to clarify.

Comment: You're still going to want to add a `.join` after the `scan`.

Comment: @Doorknob Could be, it depends on the output the OP wants. I'm happy to leave it as an array of arrays and leave any further text output as an exercise for the OP :)

Comment: That's actually an interesting paper (to me anyway). Thanks for the info.

Comment: OK, this works for me. Thank you. The outcome of this task is to determine how good a 2 way seriation is given a matrix of 1s and 0s. Two way serration details are here: innar.com/Liiv_Seriation.pdf .This is the code I cam out with: `array1 = [[1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1]] puts horizontal = array1.map{ |arr| arr.join.scan(/11+/) }.flatten.map{ |arr| arr.to_i(2) }.inject{ |sum,x| sum + x } puts vertical = array1.transpose.map{ |arr| arr.join.scan(/11+/) }.flatten.map{ |arr| arr.to_i(2) }.inject{ |sum,x| sum + x } puts score = horizontal + vertical`

Comment: By the way, feel free to edit your question to put the code you came up with in your question, it's an acceptable practice and far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

**Code**

```
array.transpose
     .map { |a|
       a.chunk { |e| e }
        .select { |f,a| f == 1 && a.size > 1 }
        .map { |_,a| a.join } }
```

**Example**

```
array = [[1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1]]
  #=> [["11", "11"], ["11"], [], ["1111"], ["111"]]
```

One could eliminate the empty set, if desired.

**Explanation**

For `array` above,

```
a = array.transpose
  #=> [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
  #    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  #    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  #    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

`a.map` iterates over the elements (rows) of `a`.  Consider the first element:

```
b = a.first
  #=> [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
c = b.chunk { |e| e }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000001020495e0>:each>
```

To view the contents of this enumerator, add `.to_a`

```
  b.chunk { |e| e }.to_a
    #=> [[1, [1, 1]], [0, [0]], [1, [1, 1]]]
d = c.select { |f,a| f == 1 && a.size > 1 }
  #=> [[1, [1, 1]], [1, [1, 1]]]
d.map { |_,a| a.join }
  #=> ["11", "11"]
```